# Transparent actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hi guys new Android developer here.

I'm currently trying to make my action bar transparent/translucent. I've already changed the background of my view to see if I'm doing this properly.

I've seen the numerous threads here but none of it is working for me.

I've tried making a custom style for my action bar and using: `<item name="android:background">#55CC00CC</item>` but this didn't work. I got a solid white color as background instead.

I also tried getting the ActionBar instance inside my activity and doing `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#55CC00CC")));` and I got this instead:

[image]

I'm trying to see if I can do this programmatically inside my activity. Some code to look at:

styles.xml:

```
<resources>  
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#55CC00CC")));
    }
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What your tested API? If I remember it right you shold use  Theme.Holo  above API 11.

Comment: I'm using API 18 atm. I kept crashing when I used @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light so I changed it back to Theme.AppCompat. Should I figure out how to use Theme.Holo first?

Comment: So you should solve the crashing problem instead of use wrong theme for the API..

Answer (score 0):

If you target for minimum API level 11 , you can change ActionBar's background color by defining custom style, as:

```
<resources>
<style name="ActionBarCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
```

And, set "ActionBarCustomTheme" as theme for application / activity.
This will do...

Comment: You can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) for more details and features.

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried following this but my app crashes whenever I use Theme.Holo.Light

Comment: Try using a custom theme using a resource XML file.

Comment: And I think your colour code is wrong. It should consist of 6 hexadecimal digits. Your code contains 8 **55CC00CC**. Refer to this [link](http://www.color-hex.com/) for example colours.

Comment: The first 2 hex values are the alpha values (the ones that sets transparency). Changing my theme to Theme.Holo fixed my problem :)

Comment: Okay. I didn't knew that. Well if its working then its cool. :)

Answer (score 0):

As `yshanak` mentioned, changing my theme to Holo instead of AppCompat fixed the problem.

To those crashing when using Holo: 
`ActionBarActivity` needs to use the AppCompat theme, so I fixed mine just by extending `Activity` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Had just fixed the same problem

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And java side part

```
  mToolbar.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                mToolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
                mToolbarLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```